# custom logging info for deployed application on jboss

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j, jboss5.x

I have an application deployed to a jboss server which uses many entityManagers because we handle many customers with one application. So we have one application talking to many DB-s

When I look at the error logs I cann not see which customer happend to find an error and sometimes it is difficult to debug the error because of this.

How is possible to ovverride the writings in the error log and put some custom info for evry log insert?

This should be possible to achive from the scope of the application because there I have all the information which user is logined etc...

We use :

jboss 5.1
seam 2.1
hibernate
log4j for logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit I don't fully understand your question, but maybe [MDC](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/11/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-example-code/) in Log4J is what you need? Using some sort of aspect/filter/proxy you can assign key-value pairs to special thread-local `MDC` object provided by Log4J. Entries from this map can be retrieved and appended to every logging statement automatically.

This mechanism, since it is local to the running thread, is very often used to display current user name/session id in every logging statement occurring in a given thread, which is very handy.

Comment: the solution for seam application is that you need to extend the saem built in LoggingFilter and set the precedence of this filter to Install.APPLICATION, there in that filter you have the acces to **MDC** and you simply put other parameters in the MDC map ant then you call tihis parameters in the jboss-log4j.xml conf file on jboss server. The parametes shoud be referenced in the ConversionPattern param for example the patern must be %d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] [%X{url}] - [%X{username}] %m%n", where %X{username} and %X{url} are parameters previously saved in MDC map

Answer (score 1):

JBoss uses a unified classloader by default, to enable application specific logging you'll want to enable classloader isolation with jboss-classloading.xml in the META-INF or WEB-INF folder.

After enabling classloader isolation, you can use log4j.xml to configure how you want the logs to work. See http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat